# List all empty checkboxes in files

Tags: org-mode, grep

Is there any easy way, including installing a package, to list all waiting checkboxes in all the files in the directory?

So far I do the following for the checkboxes in a file:

```
M-x occur - \[ \]
```

This is for the checkboxes in the whole directory and all files:

```
M-x rgrep \- \[ \]
```

**rgrep** works, but it includes a whole bunch of arguments and it's slow.

Is there any nonobvious and easy solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`M-x helm-do-grep-ag`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm), and if you're looking for speed, I'd suggest using it with the [`rg`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) command:

```
(require 'helm-grep)
(setq helm-grep-ag-command
      "rg --color=always --smart-case --no-heading --line-number %s %s %s")
```

```
1. M-x helm-do-grep-ag
2. - \[\ ]
3. TAB
4. Select "Save results in grep buffer" and press RET
```